# show for every homomorphism $\varphi$, there is a pointed map that induces it.

Tags: group-homomorphism, fundamental-groups

Im trying to show that:

For every homomorphism $\varphi:\Pi_1(S^1,1)\rightarrow\Pi_1(S^1,1)$ there is a pointed map $f:(S^1,1)\rightarrow{(S^1,1)}$ so that $\varphi=f_*$. Namely, $f$ induces $\varphi$.

Im not too sure were to start with this. We know from the homomorphism property that $\varphi([f*g])=\varphi([f]\bullet[g]])=\varphi([f])\bullet\varphi([g])$.

Comment: What are the group homomorphisms $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$?

Comment: clearly the identity map, any linear function.

Comment: Well, they are all of the form $f(x)=nx$ where $n=f(1)$. Can you find a specific $f$ for each?

Comment: a specific $f$ for each homomorphism $\varphi$? I understand that $\Pi_1(S^1,1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ so looking at homomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}$ is enough. We have homomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}$ as you've described, $\varphi(x)=nx$, so I'm looking for a pointed map that induces it.

Comment: I'm not too sure what pointed map I am to construct that will induce each of the homomorphisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A group homomorphism $\varphi:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ is determined by its value $n=\varphi(1)$, and must be of the form $\varphi=x\mapsto nx$.

Now consider $S^1$ as the set of unit complex numbers, with $1$ as the distinguished point, and verify that
$$f=x\mapsto x^n$$
induces $\varphi$ on the homotopy group.